# Can't reach server connected to another network card in the main server

Tags: networking

i have a problem here and i hope you can help me solve it.

I have one server (MainServer) with 2 network cards creating two individual networks.

Network 1:
Internal network with IP 192.10.1... and has Server1 connected with the IP 192.10.1.50

Network 2:
Network with IP 192.168.10... and has a Server2 connected with the IP 192.168.10.50
This network has a router for external connections.

I'm connecting to this Network 2 by VPN and i'm easily reaching the data stored in Server2 but i can't reach Server1.

Can anyone tell me how can i reach Server 1 "crossing" both internal networks through the network cards to get some data from that server.

I'll appreciate any help you can give and thank you in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: can you share your server's routing tables, that may help a lot.
When you ask about crossing both networks what you mean? allowing network 2 to reach network 1? or just reaching the server1 from your host? (the 2 nics addapter server)

Comment: I don't have those routing tables, only this schematic... What i mean basically is that i'm reading the tables from the Server2 already, but i need to read also the tables from Server1 which are in another network. I don't need to allow network 2 to reach network 1. I just want to reach the server1

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/5n8qt4q8l/Schematic.png

I made this schematic for you to have a clear vision of what i need to do

Comment: it is not helpful to remove your schematic .... did you resolve your issues? Was the suggested answer correct? If yes, mark it as checked.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your diagram, Main Server is the only device connected to Network 1 and which can act as a router.

If Main Server is a Windows machine, you can enable IP Forwarding by changing the following registry key and rebooting the machine:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
Value Name: IPEnableRouter
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962461.aspx

Then, either you configure a static route on the VPN device or - if you are assigned a VPN IP address in network 2 - you can manually add one to the machine you are connecting from (in this example I assume it's a windows machine):

```
route add 192.10.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 <mainserver IP on network2>
```

You should then be able to reach network 1.